# Is it possible to recruit top tier prisoners?

Tags: mount-and-blade-bannerlord

I've been dragging around 3 Karakhuzait Elder Horse Archers for roughly half a game year now, but they still refuse to be recruited into the party.  I've already drafted all the Karakhuzait Riders I had (the penultimate tier).  Should I just ransom these guys or will they turn eventually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, you're only able to recruit T4 and below prisoners due to a bug. If you have T5 and T6 then it simply isn't going to be possible to recruit them. (this suggests that they'll likely be adding a perk to charm to allow this).

https://www.reddit.com/r/mountandblade/comments/ftkb9p/bannerlord_anyone_have_confirmed_t5_prisoners/

A way to get around this it to use the following mod:

https://www.nexusmods.com/mountandblade2bannerlord/mods/112